# Issue with double and unsigned char type variables

Tags: arduino, c

I am trying the code in this [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN3397.pdf) on an Arduino mega2560 with mpu6050 IMU,

I have made some changes in the variables and I do not get errors so far.
and the code doesn't give any output, can some show me a place with wrong code work?

I get mpu6050 range accX and accY -2^15 to + 2^15. I do not post code for mpu6050 since it works. I need to serial print and see how it displacement changes in this code. 
in positionxy() function I wanted to print

```
 Sample_X =  (unsigned char)accX/129;
 Sample_Y =  (unsigned char)accY/129;     
 Serial.print ( Sample_X );  Serial.print ("\t"); 
 Serial.println ( Sample_Y ); Serial.print ("\t");
```

and it gives nothing,
i think the issue is with the variable types and i cannot figure it out. 
The part of the code as follows,

```
//all varibles 
double accX, accY, accZ;
unsigned char  Sample_X;
unsigned char  Sample_Y;
unsigned char  Sample_Z;
unsigned char  Sensor_Data[8];
unsigned char  countx,county ;
signed int  accelerationx[2], accelerationy[2];
signed long  velocityx[2], velocityy[2];
signed long  positionX[2];
signed long  positionY[2];
signed long  positionZ[2]; 
unsigned char  directionxy;
unsigned long  sstatex,sstatey;


void setup(){
 *****mpu 6050 config is done here and works aacX and accY updates with 
 current accelration value  *****
}
void loop(){
do{
Calibrate();
movement_end_check();
positionxy();  
}while(1);
}

void Calibrate() 
{
************see datasheet **********   
}


void positionxy()  
{
unsigned char count2 ;
count2=0;

do{
Sample_X =  (unsigned char)accX/129; // this line is changed 
Sample_Y =  (unsigned char)accY/129; // this line is changed
```

below serial print always gives zero

```
Serial.print ( Sample_X );  Serial.print ("\t"); 
Serial.println ( Sample_Y ); Serial.print ("\t"); 

accelerationx[1]=accelerationx[1] + Sample_X;  
accelerationy[1]=accelerationy[1] + Sample_Y;  


************see datasheet **********   
}
movement_end_check(){
************see datasheet **********   

}
```

Comment: Try printing accX and accY instead of the divided value.

Comment: @Russell Borogove Still same issue, I divided it since unsigned char can hold only 0-255, and I get -2^15 to +2^15 for the accX and accY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion to unsigned char has precedence over division.
So it first converts then divides afterwards.
Use parantheses to override:

Sample_X =  (unsigned char)(accX/129)

Comment: Sample_X gets the value update, but it does not change the value of acceleration, get same value all the time ant suggestions? i used     Serial.print ( (int8_t) accelerationx );  Serial.print ("\t"); 
    Serial.println ( (int8_t) accelerationy ); Serial.print ("\t");